# With preact, how to add event listener to a component hydrated from HTML

Tags: reactjs, preact, hydration

Consider the following HTML element:

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div>Foo</div>
</div>
```

How can I write a preact component that, when hydrated from this HTML element, would add event listener to the inner `div` - typically a `onclick` listener?

It is explicitely written in preact documentation that the `hydrate` function _skips most diffing while still attaching event listeners _, but at no point do they explain how to attach the event listeners.

If I write the following component:

```js
const Foo: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    return <><div onClick={() => alert("click");}></div></>;
}
```

And hydrate it from the HTML element this way:

```js
import {hydrate} from "preact";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const fooElement = document.getElementById('foo');

    hydrate(<Foo />, fooElement!); 
}
```

Then the content of the div (i.e., "foo") is not hydrated into the rendered component. The only way for the content of the div to be hydrated into the rendered component is to write the component this way:

```js
const Foo: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    return <></>;
}
```

But as you can guess, there is no way to add an event listener with this method.

So, how can we hydrate a component using an HTML element - preserving the HTML element data - and add event listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hydrate a component, Preact assumes that the existing HTML matches what the component would render on its first render.

So, if your server-rendered HTML is:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>Foo</div>
</div>
```

Your Preact component should also render the same HTML structure on its first render for hydration to work as expected.

Here's how you can modify your Foo component to add an onClick listener to the inner div.

```
const Foo = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => alert('Clicked!')}>Foo</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And for hydrating:

```
import { hydrate } from "preact";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const fooElement = document.getElementById('foo');
    hydrate(<Foo />, fooElement);
});
```

This will hydrate the component and attach the onClick event listener to the inner div.

However, if you really want to preserve the inner HTML ('Foo' in this case) and attach an event listener, you may need to resort to using native DOM methods within a useEffect or componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Comment: Thanks. I does not make much sense to me why React doesn't actually hydrate the div inner HTML from the passed HTML element - if it requires that the existing HTML matches the one rendered by the component, this must be for something, right? And well, the name of the function is...hydrate. :D Anyway, your answer is legit, thanks a lot. I'll try to understand how to preserve the inner HTML but maybe React is not the best library for that.

Comment: @EricMORAND Preact maintainer here -- the entire idea and purpose of hydration is that it's a fast-pass around rendering, skipping the heavy work (diffing) that's already been done server side and just hooking up the event listeners. If you don't care about the performance and just want to blow away the inner content, use `render()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I'm still not sure why it is named hydrate if it does not hydrate the component with the data of the HTML element. This is exactly what hydration is about: filling an object with data. Here it does not fill the component with data. Hence my confusion. I thought it would allow to transform an HTML element into a reactive component - i.e. adding behaviour - in a declarative way, without changing its content. Or maybe I missed something obvious.

Comment: "This is exactly what hydration is about: filling an object with data" -- Sorry, but this is incorrect. Hydration is the the act of adding interactivity to static markup, aka, adding event listeners. This is true across all major frontend frameworks and even Wikipedia has this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_(web_development). If you want to change an element, you need to render it.